# CPython and threading module Lock()

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, cpython

Since CPython  has the  GIL, no threads are allowed to execute python code at the same time, thus there seems to be thread safety within a given process.

What is the purpose then of the python threading module `Lock ()`? What synchronization  problems can still  occur in CPython  that the `Lock ()` helps with even though no threads can execute at the same time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GIL only makes sure that only one thread can run at a time. It is still possible that a thread gets interrupted between instructions and another thread has a chance to run. Therefore if two threads access a shared resource the access needs to be protected with a lock.

Let's take this example:

```
from threading import Thread

i = 0

def func():
    global i
    while i < 1000000:
        i += 1
        if i != i:
            print("i was modified")

for _ in range(10):
    Thread(target=func).start()
```

Although it looks like the `if` condition can't possibly ever be true, there is a good chance that you'll see the line printed. How can that be?

If you look at the disassembled bytecode of `func` (by calling `dis.dis(func)` from the `dis` module), this is what you'll get:

```
  7           0 SETUP_LOOP              51 (to 54)
        >>    3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (i)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000000)
              9 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             12 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       53

  8          15 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (i)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             21 INPLACE_ADD
             22 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (i)

  9          25 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (i)
             28 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (i)
             31 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
             34 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        3

 10          37 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print)
             40 LOAD_CONST               3 ('i was modified')
             43 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             46 POP_TOP
             47 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
             50 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   53 POP_BLOCK
        >>   54 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             57 RETURN_VALUE
```

The relevant instructions are 25 and 28. If the thread gets interrupted between those two instructions, another therad can modify the global variable `i` and the stored values will be different.

Comment: Really nice answer ! Thank you